# Backslash not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

The two <kbd>AltGr</kbd> keys right next to the <kbd>0</kbd> are not working, the first one, the backslash is pretty handy... When I run [On-Screen Keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command#List_of_commands) (osk.exe) to reveal the keyboard it looks the same. It also presumes pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the key to the right of the <kbd>0</kbd> should produce a backslash... but nothing. So not with the On-Screen Keyboard and not with the keyboard.

All the rest of the keys, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations work fine. The only way I can make it work is to switch to the US keyboard, start On-Screen Keyboard, click the slash and switch back to the Dutch keyboard (for every slash).

So I went through diverse keyboard setups but nothing. Is it something stupid?

Platform:

- Windows 7
- [ThinkPad T60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_T_Series#History)
- [Dutch keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dutch_.28Netherlands.29)

Comment: Do other keys that require pressing `AltGr` work, or is it with every combination? Does it work when you press `Ctrl+Alt` instead of `AltGr`?

Comment: no Ctrl+Alt . All other keys work as stated. However... I read some more and I AM working on a remote desktop connection. I read an MSDN article that the top right keys are not available during an RDP session.... so.......... I only have my workaround by constantly switching...